# get the data of dropdownlist in html from asp

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I want get values of asp(server side) using html(client side) drop down list .
when click `dropdownlist` button in html it should load asp values and my senior said use web method but I don't know web services, is there any possible to solve this?

asp (getting data from database)

```
public void BindDropDownListData(){
   string cs = "server=.;uid=sam;pwd=p@ssw0rd;database=SSP";
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)){
      try{
           con.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PCode,PName from SMSQUARE", con);
           SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           sda.Fill(dt);
           ddlprojects.DataSource = dt;
           ddlprojects.DataTextField = "PrjName";
           ddlprojects.DataValueField = "prjcode";
           ddlprojects.DataBind();
       }
       catch (Exception e){
          Response.Write(e.Message.ToString());
       }
```

Above data I want load below html `dropdownlist`

html

```
<td>
    <select name="ddlProjects" id="ddlProjects" tabindex="1" onchange="ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged" class="dropdown"></select>
</td>
```

Comment: I'm guess to make a function a `webmethod` you have to add an attribute. You can refer following [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/287430/Calling-ASP-Net-WebMethods-using-jQuery)

Comment: "get values of asp(server side)" this makes no sense (unless you want a list of pages?).

Answer (score 0):

first of all add *using System.Web.Services* to namespaces
add next code into aspx page into header, and of course add jquery reference:

```
$("#ddlProjects").click(function () {
    var adID = $('#cphRateAd_hidden_adv_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CodeBehind.aspx/Method",
        data: "{param: '" + 1}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            //some actions if you need
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Can not load values');
        }
    });
});
```

CodeBehind.aspx is your code behind page, Method is your method that will process data. In code behind your method will be

```
[WebMethod]
public static void BindDropDownListData(int param)
{//param is for nothing,     just parameter
    string cs = "server=.;uid=sam;pwd=p@ssw0rd;database=SSP";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PCode,PName from SMSQUARE", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            ddlprojects.DataSource = dt;
            ddlprojects.DataTextField = "PrjName";
            ddlprojects.DataValueField = "prjcode";
            ddlprojects.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```